# Different json object on every request

Tags: ios, swift, api, github-api

I'm trying to create an iOS application with Github activity feed in the table or in the collection view.

The endpoint I'm hooking at is [here](https://api.github.com/events).

And the API Doc is [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#deleteevent)

I can create Swift native objects depend on JSON but there has been written in API doc that payload object is different based on state. There is approximately a different 40 payload object.

How can I parse this type of json? Where the object is different on every request.

Should I create 40 different objects? I think it is not a smart way to do it.

Comment: maybe you can work with a dictionary and checking for keys that you need??

Comment: It depends on what exact information you want to retrieve. The API seems to be very complete and if you want to support all different `Events`, you will have to write some logic in some way. You most likely don't need to parse *all* the information that you get from the endpoint, so you could define a smaller subset of types.

Comment: It is coding interview challenge from the remote company and they really didn't say that I can parse a smaller subset of types. But eventually I can do it of course and If there is not any other solution I will do that. Thank you for your responses

Comment: I think that's an open question. I didn't analyse each response. But depending on what fields/values you want, you might group them (class/subsclass, substructs for parts of the keys, etc.) or not.